# disabling/enabling access/download for user but allow php to edit - using chown and chmod

Tags: php

I want ...

- `move_uploaded_files` to some folder (lets say `http://localhost/myproject/protected`). (and PHP should be able to `rm`, `mv`, `cp`, ... everything inside `protected`)
- enable/disable access/download for user for any file, for example `http://my.ip.add.ress/myproject/protected/foo.bar` (and `http://localhost/myproject/protected/foo.bar` is not exception !)

... using `chmod` and `chown`. **I wonder if this is possible ?!**

---

P.S. I have an idea :

```
// firstly chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

<?php
    //file : localhost/myproject/foo.php
    //use following when access for user is disabled

    shell_exec("chmod -R 0777 protected");

    // edit the folder ...
    // edit the folder ...
    // edit the folder ...

    shell_exec("chmod -R 0000 protected");
?>
```

But I don't think it is secure enough :-{|)

O.M.T. (One More Thing) I did following :

- `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`
- `chmod -R 0700 /var/www/myproject/protected`

PHP can access the files, but user can also access them.

---

**EDIT 1** : Output for `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` :

```
root     12748  0.0  0.2  39984  8256 ?        Ss   01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12755  0.0  0.1  40208  6008 ?        S    01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12756  0.0  0.1  40008  4324 ?        S    01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12757  0.0  0.1  40008  4324 ?        S    01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12758  0.0  0.1  40008  4324 ?        S    01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12759  0.0  0.1  40008  4324 ?        S    01:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
sylap    12896  0.0  0.0   5904   860 pts/1    S+   02:25   0:00 egrep --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not change any **chmod** you just need to **chown** to **apache** then only your php codes is able to modify this

```
// File name and username to use
$file_name= "foo.php";
$path = "/home/sites/php.net/public_html/sandbox/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "apache";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);
```

Comment: `sudo chown -R apache protect/foo.bar` chown: invalid user: ‘apache’, tried `$user_name = "www-data"` still downloadable :(

Comment: ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)' typically will show what apache is running as.

Comment: default user, usually is "nobody" or "apache"